# How to turn off Xcode 6 autoindent text files

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I use a text file (History.txt) for notes and to keep track of my edits.  Xcode 6 is applying the indentation rules to all files, and so manual formatting (using tabs) in my text file is changed when I type a line or copy and paste.  For example, typing a semicolon causes a line with leading whitespace to left justify.  Prior versions of Xcode didn't do this.

I must have autoindent on for my source code files.

How can I tell Xcode 6 to leave my .txt files alone (no auto indent)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. Didn't find a proper solution, but a workaround is to turn off the auto-indent feature (under Preferences -> Text Editing -> Indentation) for the specific characters that you use a lot in your text files (in my case the colon character was the main culprit) and that you can learn to live without having auto-indent when actually editing code. It's a decent way to get around this problem.

Comment: I'll try your colon suggestion.  The better of two evils.  Meanwhile, please file your own bug report with Apple.  (I doubt this has been fixed in 6.2 or 6.3, but I haven't' checked.)